# How to get linux start a script when files did changed

Tags: linux, scripting, doxygen, trac

i'm not that good configuring a linux server. So i hope someone can give me a hint for my problem.

I have installed trac for managing projects. It contains a plugin for doxygen. As far as i know i need to generate the doxygen output by myself. So i was thinking if it is possible to start a script when any file in a folder did changed.

Is there any way to get this done by a shell script? Or do i need to create a daemon for this?

Answer (score 2):

Inotify is your friend.

Check out something like:

- inotify-tools: https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools
- incron: http://linuxaria.com/article/incron-cron-inotify?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

A `Makefile` and a `cron` job that runs `make` every X minutes should suffice. See `info make` and `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: This is essentially what I do on my setup and it works great.  If you'd prefer, you can use a shell script instead of `make` (that's what I do).